# Using "chats" argument in telethon.events

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I'm running this:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChat, PeerChannel

@client.on(events.ChatAction(chats=[PeerChannel(-1001244988104)]))
async def handle_chat_action(event):
    print(event)
    print(event.user_left)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[PeerChat(-100123456789)]))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

But, not getting updates, why? What's wrong here?

At first, I tried `chats=[-100123456]` (without PeerChat), but did not get updates...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should not mix the concept of "marked IDs" and `Peer` instances together. You can use:

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[PeerChannel(123456789)]))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)
```

Or:

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[-100123456789]))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)
```

But not both.

- The `-100` prefix tells Telethon it's a [`Channel`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/channel.html) (megagroups, also known as supergroups, are also `Channel`).
- The `-` prefix tells Telethon it's a [`Chat`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/chat.html).
- The `+` prefix tells Telethon it's a [`User`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/user.html).

This follows the same convention as the [Telegram HTTP Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

If you don't use a prefix, Telethon will look in cache for all types. If it's not in cache, it will attempt to use a `User`.

If you use a prefix, Telethon will only get that type from cache. If it's not in cache, it will attempt to use the type your prefix says.

Internally,

```py
-100123 == PeerChannel(123)
-123 == PeerChat(123)
123 == PeerUser(123)
```

`event.chat_id`, `event.user_id`, `client.get_peer_id` all return prefixed IDs because it's helpful for the library and convenient for the user.

Updates are the "raw" objects from Telegram and those are the original, real values.

Comment: Thank for a great explanation! I also noticed that was not getting an update because of the `pattern` argument before `chats`. I removed it, started to get updates